# form data displaying in a table that is in a different file (javascript only)

Tags: javascript, html

I have created two html files where one is form data and the other is a table but not too sure how the local storage can do this. All form data must be stored in the columns in the table but must be on a separate page. Can anyone help?

**testing.html:**

```
<html>

<body>
  <form id="formSellItem">
    <label>Item name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtItemName" name="itemName" required="required"><br> <br>

    <label>Item description:</label><br>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtItemDesc" name="itemDesc"></textarea><br><br>

    <label>Price:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtPrice" name="price" required="required"><br> <br>

    <input type="submit" id="btnSaveItem" value="Save">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**testing1.html:**

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Item List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Item list</h2>
  <table border="1" id="tableAllItems">
    <tr class="aligncenter" style="font-weight: bold;">
      <th>Item no</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Desc</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Action1</th>
      <th>Action2</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1) On save, do `getItem` to know if there is data in the localStorage then append new data, then do `setItem` to update the data in the localStorage
2.) Then in the table just do `getItem` and display

Comment: Is it possible for you to shoe me by adding the js and comments please??

Comment: You need to at least try something. Try reading [this](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/)

Comment: I have got it to the point where every item is in local storage and i can display it in plain text but now i need to added to the table

Answer (score 0):

Save the form data into javascript object. Use JSON.stringify() method, to convert that object into json, and set to the localstorage. For render on the table, just convert back that json into js object with JSON.parse() method, and looping inside the table.